# Number of same line in each text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, duplicate

I have more then 30 different text files and each one of them has a same word which repeated different time for example in text1 "esr" repeated 12 times and in text2 "esr" repeated 21 times.

Is it possible to output the number of time that the word repeated separately with one command?

Comment: "repeated separately"? The sum of all the occurrences, or the number of occurrences in each file, but presented separately?

Comment: @Kusalananda the number of occurrences in separate format

Comment: are you interested specifically in "esr" or every word that can be found in any file ?

Comment: Your title is completely different that what you described in body of your question! if it's title  then `sort <file | uniq -c` would be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ***grep*** + ***wc*** pipeline:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo -n "$f "; grep -wo 'esr' "$f" | wc -l; done
```

---

*grep* options:

- `-w` - word-regexp (to match whole/separate word)
- `-o` - print only matched substrings

---

- `wc -l` - count the number of lines (matched words in our case) for each file

Comment: Why not just `grep -wc esr *txt`?

Comment: @terdon, to print the filename along with count `filename count`

Comment: The file name is printed when you give `grep` multiple input files (and you can force it to do it with `-H` anyway) so that's not an issue. However, my suggestion will not count multiple occurrences on the same line, while yours does.

Comment: @terdon, exactly

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
strings ./*.txt|tr " " "\n"|sort|uniq -c
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to find all instances, then count unique lines using [`uniq -c`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq).

```
grep "word" * | sort | uniq -c
```

If you want matches per input file, use `grep -c`:

```
grep -c "word" *
```

Comment: This will unfortunately miscount if the pattern occurs several times on the same line.

Comment: this will match `anywordlike this` and will count it

Answer (score 2):

```
for name in file*.txt; do
    printf 'Pattern occurs %d times in "%s"\n' "$(grep -wo 'pattern' "$name" | wc -l)" "$name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count every word in any number of files you could use `AWK` e.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"}
     {counts[$0]++}
     END{for(word in counts){print word " - " counts[word]}
     ' file1 file2 file...
```

This treats a file as if every word were on a separate line, *that's the* `BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"}` *part*, then counts each time it sees a *line*. 
Removing the `BEGIN` portion would count each *normal* line.

If you're only interested in 1 specific word, you could change the `END` block to look something like:

```
END{print counts["esr"]}
```

Which would print only the times "esr" shows up, but remember that this is case-sensitive.

To remove case-sensitivity, use `counts[tolower($0)]++` or `counts[toupper($0)]++`.

Checks can be added to print out data when the count goes from one file to the next as well.